# Simple software license key server suggestions?

Tags: c++, web-services, licensing, service, activation

My boss wants a quick, simple to integrate, simple to host software licensing server to enforce license activations and expirations. We have to integrate it with a C++ Windows Service application.

I would not like to host the service in our office for the same reason we don't host our own website in our office. The service must be host-able in "the cloud" or at a normal web hosting company (for instance, a SOAP service that runs over HTTPS).

We would like a simple royalty-free solution. Any suggestions other than building our own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>[Flexnet Publisher](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/producer/products/software-monetization/flexnet-licensing/tab/features/subtab/flexnet-publisher) does what you want - not sure of pricing model though.</strike>

EDIT: Flexnet appear to be pricey and non-hosted. Try this thread for more options:

<strike>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443064/alternatives-to-flexnet-publisher-reprise</strike> (Dead)

[Orion](http://www.agilis-sw.com/orion/) looks promising.

EDIT 2: The SO thread above was removed. Some alternatives to Flexnet Publisher can be found on [alternativeTo](http://alternativeto.net/software/flexnet-publisher/).

Comment: Thanks for the link to that other thread. I looked at Orion, but as soon as I saw that there was no pricing on their website, I knew it was too much. I called them to confirm...they don't sell it royalty free. They want a piece of your action! The guy's like "We sell a yearly subscription based licensed based on your _projected_ revenues." All can I say is EFFFF THAT!

Comment: @wizlb - you will be lucky to find a cheap, effective solution imo. This is not a simple thing to do well. Good luck all the same.

Comment: So far, I found ElecKey which is royalty free and cheap (around $1,500). - http://www.sciensoft.com/ It comes with an activation web service or stand alone server and it does all sorts of licensing models. Going to spend a couple days looking around though. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @wizlb - post your answer when you get back from your search - if it's still the best solution, you can accept it yourself (there's a badge for that :-)

Comment: @wizlb, did you guys go with ElecKey?  Any comments on how that worked for you?  I am looking for same thing, preferably Java based.

Answer (score 3):

I'll dig up this thread too. I'm currently looking at http://wyday.com/limelm/ which is a paid service but seems a lot cheaper than most.